# SQL Server view design

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database that I'm running large queries against that I want to simplify with a view. Though there's more of them, the tables basically look like this (pseudo code):

```
TABLE document (
Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    /*more metadata columns*/
)

TABLE name (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    documentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES document.Id,
    date DATETIME,
    text varchar(MAX)
)

TABLE description (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    documentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES document.Id,
    date DATETIME,
    text varchar(MAX)
)
```

So the idea is that the 'document' table contains the basic information about a document and the Id that ties the rest of the tables to the document. All other tables are for individual attributes of the document that are updateable. Each update gets its own row with a timestamp. What I want the view to pull is one row per document with the most up to date versions of each attribute contained in the other tables (if this needs further elaboration or an example, please let me know and I will provide). What is the least convoluted way I can pull this off? Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @marc_s, I appreciate you taking the time to edit my post, but I don't believe changing the title from "SQL View design" to "SQL Server view design" was warranted. The solution to this issue could very well be platform independent, and thus useful to those using database software other than that by Microsoft.

Comment: if you want a fast, efficient view then there is no portable solution. The fact of "SQL Server" matters immensely: this would be ugly as sin in MySQL for example

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance of MySql, but wouldn't a materialized view lend a similar performance gain with similar code?

Comment: If you don't like it - feel free to change the title back - but it **IS** about SQL Server and as gbn already pointed out: lots of things are way beyond the SQL standards an into vendor-specific features, so knowing what database system you're using (instead of the generic "SQL") is actually **beneficial** - not a drawback (in my opinion). But hey - it's your question - edit the title as you see fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CTE for each attribute inside the view to return the latest attribute values for the documentid, like so:

```
; WITH cName AS
(SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT ID, documentID, 
       date, text, 
       ranking = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY documentID ORDER BY date DESC)
      FROM name) x
WHERE ranking = 1),
.... [more CTE's here]
SELECT columnlist
FROM document d JOIN cName cn ON d.id=cn.documentid
```

Answer (score 4):

A view won't increase efficiency. A view is just a macro that expands.

There is no magic in a view: but can suffer if you join onto this view because the expanded queries can get massive.

You can index a view, but these work best with Enterprise Edition unless you want to use the NOEXPAND hint all over.

That said, the query is quite easy: unless you want to index the view when you have limitations.

One approach is the CTE as per Stuart Ainsworth's approach. Another is the "Max one per group" approach I described [here on dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004). Neither of these are safe for [indexed views.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004)

Comment: Sorry, should have specified indexed view. Updating original post so I don't get repeatedly hammered on that point.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last to points you made in this answer? ie "...unless you want to index the view when you have limitations," and "Neither of these are safe for indexed views."

Answer (score 0):

Sql server 2008 supports computed column in the index. So you could set a column - "is_latest" as 1 for the row with latest time for that document_id. Now while querying you could use the is_latest column and it would be much faster. Refer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx